# Using LLVM IR, how do I transform a function with non-void return into a void return type

Tags: c++, function, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

Is there a existing method to transform functions with non-void return types into ones with a void return type?

I need all the functions in my program (besides main) to have a void return type to work properly with my research/optimization.

I presume the implementation would create an alloc for the return value, create a new function and insert the alloc into the arguments, save the value in the alloc, and then load the value after the function complete and the call has returned.

I figure *someone* must have done this already :)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds fairly straightforward to code as a module pass, but you need to have full visibility on the program to do that. It means you can call a libC function (unless you're having the implementation as part of an LTO link for example).